# Delay in scroll fixed position for ios safari browser only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a certain scrolling functionality set for when this site is viewed on a mobile device (<500). [magainteractive.com](http://magainteractive.com/prototypes/aiga-design-census/)

The headers for the sections are supposed to stick to the top as you scroll down. It works perfectly on chrome mobile browser, but not on safari ios. You can see that there's a delay when the headers try to stick to the top on scroll. If I remove the last two headers in my html, then the headers stick to the top without any delay. Any workaround for this? Not sure why the addition of the last two headers is causing the issue.

If you open my site in safari responsive mode (iPhone), you can see how the headers act different than in chrome.

This is the javascript code I am using for the sticky headers:

```
function mobileScrollInit(){
    console.log("Mobile initiate");
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });

    var stickyHeaders = (function() {

        var $stickies;
        var topOffset = new Array();

        var load = function(stickies, target) {

            if (typeof stickies === "object" && stickies instanceof jQuery && stickies.length > 0) {

                $stickies = stickies.each(function(index,element) {

                    var $thisSticky = $(this);

                    //for each header, get the height and top position
                    $thisSticky
                    .data('originalPosition', $thisSticky.offset().top)
                    .data('originalHeight', $thisSticky.outerHeight()); 

                    console.log("Index is: "+index);
                    console.log("Offset: "+$thisSticky.offset().top);

                    topOffset.push($thisSticky.data('originalPosition'));

                });

                //only on scroll, run function
                target.off("scroll.stickies").on("scroll.stickies", function(event) {
                    _whenScrolling(event);  
                });
            }
        };

        var _whenScrolling = function(event) {
            //get scrolling position
            var $scrollTop = $(event.currentTarget).scrollTop();
            console.log($scrollTop);    
            var scrolled = 0;
            var count = 0;


            $stickies.each(function(index,value) {          

                var $thisSticky = $(this),
                    //$stickyPosition = $stickies[count].data('originalPosition'),
                    $stickyHeight = $thisSticky.data('originalHeight'),
                    $nextStickyHeight = 0,
                    $newPosition,
                    $nextSticky;


                $nextSticky = $stickies.eq(index + 1);
                $nextStickyHeight = $stickies.eq(index + 1).outerHeight();


                //if last header
                if ($scrollTop >= topOffset[$stickies.length - 1]) {
                    console.log("Reached the end");
                    var $lastStickyElement = $stickies.eq($stickies.length - 1);

                    $lastStickyElement.addClass("header--fixed");
                    $lastStickyElement.css({
                        "top": 0
                    });

                    $nextSticky.removeClass("header--fixed");
                    $nextSticky.addClass("header--static");


                    $('.screen_inner_holder').css({
                        "padding-top": $stickyHeight
                    });
                }

                //if you scroll past the header nav
                else if ($scrollTop >= topOffset[count] && $scrollTop < topOffset[count + 1]) {

                    scrolled = 1;

                    //push up the next one
                    var triggerToPushUp = (topOffset[count + 1] - $stickyHeight);
                    if($scrollTop >= triggerToPushUp && topOffset[count + 1] > $scrollTop) {

                        $thisSticky.css({
                            "top": -($scrollTop - triggerToPushUp)
                        });


                        $nextSticky.removeClass("header--static");
                        $nextSticky.addClass("header--fixed");
                        $nextSticky.css({
                            "top": topOffset[count + 1] - $scrollTop,
                        });

                        $('.screen_inner_holder').css({
                            "padding-top": $stickyHeight + $nextStickyHeight
                        });

                        console.log("Scroll top is greater that: " + triggerToPushUp);
                        console.log("Pushing sticky up");

                        return false;
                    }

                    else {
                        $thisSticky.removeClass("header--static");
                        $thisSticky.addClass("header--fixed");

                        $thisSticky.css({
                            "top": 0
                        });

                        $nextSticky.removeClass("header--fixed");
                        $nextSticky.addClass("header--st
    function mobileScrollInit(){
    console.log("Mobile initiate");
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 });

    var stickyHeaders = (function() {

        var $stickies;
        var topOffset = new Array();

        var load = function(stickies, target) {

            if (typeof stickies === "object" && stickies instanceof jQuery && stickies.length > 0) {

                $stickies = stickies.each(function(index,element) {

                    var $thisSticky = $(this);

                    //for each header, get the height and top position
                    $thisSticky
                    .data('originalPosition', $thisSticky.offset().top)
                    .data('originalHeight', $thisSticky.outerHeight()); 

                    console.log("Index is: "+index);
                    console.log("Offset: "+$thisSticky.offset().top);

                    topOffset.push($thisSticky.data('originalPosition'));

                });

                //only on scroll, run function
                target.off("scroll.stickies").on("scroll.stickies", function(event) {
                    _whenScrolling(event);  
                });
            }
        };

        var _whenScrolling = function(event) {
            //get scrolling position
            var $scrollTop = $(event.currentTarget).scrollTop();
            console.log($scrollTop);    
            var scrolled = 0;
            var count = 0;


            $stickies.each(function(index,value) {          

                var $thisSticky = $(this),
                    //$stickyPosition = $stickies[count].data('originalPosition'),
                    $stickyHeight = $thisSticky.data('originalHeight'),
                    $nextStickyHeight = 0,
                    $newPosition,
                    $nextSticky;


                $nextSticky = $stickies.eq(index + 1);
                $nextStickyHeight = $stickies.eq(index + 1).outerHeight();


                //if last header
                if ($scrollTop >= topOffset[$stickies.length - 1]) {
                    console.log("Reached the end");
                    var $lastStickyElement = $stickies.eq($stickies.length - 1);

                    $lastStickyElement.addClass("header--fixed");
                    $lastStickyElement.css({
                        "top": 0
                    });

                    $nextSticky.removeClass("header--fixed");
                    $nextSticky.addClass("header--static");


                    $('.screen_inner_holder').css({
                        "padding-top": $stickyHeight
                    });
                }

                //if you scroll past the header nav
                else if ($scrollTop >= topOffset[count] && $scrollTop < topOffset[count + 1]) {

                    scrolled = 1;

                    //push up the next one
                    var triggerToPushUp = (topOffset[count + 1] - $stickyHeight);
                    if($scrollTop >= triggerToPushUp && topOffset[count + 1] > $scrollTop) {

                        $thisSticky.css({
                            "top": -($scrollTop - triggerToPushUp)
                        });


                        $nextSticky.removeClass("header--static");
                        $nextSticky.addClass("header--fixed");
                        $nextSticky.css({
                            "top": topOffset[count + 1] - $scrollTop,
                        });

                        $('.screen_inner_holder').css({
                            "padding-top": $stickyHeight + $nextStickyHeight
                        });

                        console.log("Scroll top is greater that: " + triggerToPushUp);
                        console.log("Pushing sticky up");

                        return false;
                    }

                    else {
                        $thisSticky.removeClass("header--static");
                        $thisSticky.addClass("header--fixed");

                        $thisSticky.css({
                            "top": 0
                        });

                        $nextSticky.removeClass("header--fixed");
                        $nextSticky.addClass("header--static");


                        $('.screen_inner_holder').css({
                            "padding-top": $stickyHeight
                        });
                    }

                }

                //if you haven't scrolled past any headers
                else {
                    $(this).removeClass("header--fixed");
                    $(this).addClass("header--static");
                }


                count++; 

            });

            if (scrolled == 0) {
                $('.screen_inner_holder').css({
                    "padding-top": 0
                });
            }
        };


        return {
            load: load
        };

    })();

    $(function() {
      stickyHeaders.load($(".header"), $(window));
    });
}
```